# how can I make bootstrap respondsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am currently taking a course on Udemy and it is about Bootstrap, well the problem is that the course was released since 2018, and now while I am following along, there are a lots things that are not responsive. like  text wont get the size assigned to it, or the front assign to it. it is supper annoying.
if someone understand what is going on, please help!
[The  is not taking the parameters assigned to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJlil.png)

```css
#title{
  background-color:#FF4C68;
  color: #fff;
}
body{
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}
h1{
  font-size:12rem;
  line-height:1.5;
  font-family:"Montserrat-Black";

}
h2{
  font-size:3rem;
  line-height:1.5;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:"Montserrat-bold";

}
h3{
  word-wrap: break-word;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    -o-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
}
p{
  color:#8f8f8f;
}

.container-fluid{
  padding:3% 15%;
}
.rotate{
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
/* mavigationbar */
.navbar{
  padding-bottom:8.5rem;
}
.navbar-brand{
  font-size:2.5rem;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:"Ubuntu"

}
.nav-item{
  padding: 0 18px;
}
.nav-link{
  font-size:1.12rem;
  font-family: "Montserrat-light"
}
/* Download buttons */
.Download-button{
  margin:5% 3% 5% 0;
}
/* image tittle */
.title-image{
  width:40%;
}
/* features-section */
#features{
  padding:7% 15%;
}
.feature-box{
  text-align:center;
  padding:5%;
}
.icon{
  color: #EF8172;
  margin-bottom:2rem;
}
.icon:hover{
  color: #FF4C68;
}

/* testimonial section */
#testimonials{
  padding: 7% 15%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color:#EF8172;
  color:#fff;
}
.testimonial-image{
  width:55%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TinDog</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <!-- google font -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital@1&family=Ubuntu:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat+Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet" > -->
  <!-- bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- awsomefont -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/89569a1c7f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <section id="title">

    <div class="container-fluid">


      <!-- Nav Bar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Tindog</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <!-- Title -->

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 ">
          <h1>Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg download-button" ><i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Download</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg download-button"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 ">
          <img class="title-image" src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>


  <!-- Features -->


  <section id="features">
    <div class="row">

    <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
      <i class="icon fas fa-check fa-4x"></i>
      <h3 >Easy to use.</h3>
      <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
    </div>

    <div class=" feature-box col-lg-4">
      <i class="icon fas fa-bullseye fa-4x"></i>
      <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
      <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>
    </div>

    <div class=" feature-box col-lg-4">
      <i class="icon fas fa-heart fa-4x"></i>
      <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
      <p>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  </section>


  <!-- Testimonials -->

  <section id="testimonials">

    <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
    <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
    <em>Pebbles, New York</em>

    <!-- <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
    <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
    <em>Beverly, Illinois</em> -->

  </section>


  <!-- Press -->

  <section id="press">
    <img src="images/techcrunch.png" alt="tc-logo">
    <img src="images/tnw.png" alt="tnw-logo">
    <img src="images/bizinsider.png" alt="biz-insider-logo">
    <img src="images/mashable.png" alt="mashable-logo">

  </section>


  <!-- Pricing -->

  <section id="pricing">

    <h2>A Plan for Every Dog's Needs</h2>
    <p>Simple and affordable price plans for your and your dog.</p>


    <h3>Chihuahua</h3>
    <h2>Free</h2>
    <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
    <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
    <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
    <button type="button">Sign Up</button>


    <h3>Labrador</h3>
    <h2>$49 / mo</h2>
    <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
    <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
    <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
    <button type="button">Sign Up</button>


    <h3>Mastiff</h3>
    <h2>$99 / mo</h2>
    <p>Pirority Listing</p>
    <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
    <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
    <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
    <button type="button">Sign Up</button>

  </section>


  <!-- Call to Action -->

  <section id="cta">

    <h3>Find the True Love of Your Dog's Life Today.</h3>
    <button type="button">Download</button>
    <button type="button">Download</button>

  </section>


  <!-- Footer -->

  <footer id="footer">

    <p>© Copyright 2018 TinDog</p>

  </footer>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: For a start you seem to be missing many of the important layout classes related to Bootstrap. I'm not sure what course you are doing on Udemy, but I don't think it is teaching you BS effectively. The docs are the best place to start - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/. You are probably dealing with specificity too which is probably why styling won't be assigned - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: I just posted the whole file, you can always take a look....and I do not think so, I have learn a lot from that course, and it is just some small stuff that not really working, and I would like to know why.

Comment: Have you tried using <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0"/> in the <head> of your HTML? Also, using "@media only screen and" in your CSS works for responsive pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current layout appears to be responsive. Based on the limited `col` classes you have assigned.

However, your issue is not down to responsiveness (how it reacts to viewport changes) but styling. It is likely to do with the order of your stylesheets.

Your Bootstrap styles should be first, followed by your custom styles - CSS - Cascading Style Sheets - You are effectively adding styles on-top of the Bootstrap ones (which is why you will often run into specificity issues with Bootstrap).

What is currently happening is you custom styles are being loaded, then being overwritten by the Bootstrap stylesheet. You of course want this the other way around.

I would suggest something like this

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TinDog</title>
  <!-- bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- google font -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital@1&family=Ubuntu:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat+Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet" > -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  
  
  <!-- awsomefont -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/89569a1c7f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe link your css after your bootstrap and see if it works.